# how to adjust distance between to bars in bar chart highchart

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts, react-highcharts, angular-highcharts

[highchart issue screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oa43H.png)

I want to adjust the highhcart bars spacing, I want to remove gaps and overllaping issue on two bar charts

Comment: You need to show code please showing what you have tried and show your issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the gap by using `groupPadding` property. To remove the space between two columns in one group, set `pointPadding` and `borderWidth` to 0.

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        borderWidth: 0,
        groupPadding: 0.1,
        pointPadding: 0
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uhkfj93w/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.pointPadding

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.groupPadding

Comment: after increasing group padding, its decreasing the size of bar @ppotaczek

Comment: Hi @Juberkhan Pathan, So, you need to increase `chart.height`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vkw02s35/